# RadToolTip not showing when using a custom asp.net .ashx image handler

Tags: asp.net, telerik, tooltip

Hi im using the RadToolTip.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgMain" runat="server"/>
    <telerik:RadToolTip ID="RadToolTip2" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgMain" Width="400px" RelativeTo="Element" EnableShadow="true" Position="BottomCenter" Animation="Slide"            AnimationDuration="300" ShowDelay="200" Skin="Vista" HideEvent="LeaveToolTip">
    </telerik:RadToolTip>
```

Im also adding a Image inside the RadToolTip at runtime, the ImageUrl of this Image is set via my own custom Image Handler which is used within the site and works fine.

When the user hovers over 'imgMain' the RadToolTip should show the same image but at a different size, but all im getting is the RadToolTip showing the title.
If i hard code the Image Urls into the Image inside the RadToolTip is shows fine so i know its not a problem with my ImageHandler.

Is there any known issues with dynamically showing images from a Image Handler inside a RadToolTip?

My Server side code is below

```
imgMain.ImageUrl = String.Format("~/dbimagehandler.ashx?record=product&empty=showt&imageno=1&recno=-1&wid={0}&hgt={1}&productid={2}", "188", "196", this.ProductId)

imgMain.AlternateText = ds.Ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
imgMain.ToolTip = ds.Ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();

RadToolTip2.TargetControlID = imgMain.ID;
Image imgsmall = new Image();
imgsmall.ImageUrl = String.Format("~/dbimagehandler.ashx?record=product&empty=showt&imageno=1amprecno=-1&wid={0}&hgt={1}&productid={2}", "376","392", this.ProductId);
RadToolTip2.Controls.Add(imgsmall);
```

Any help on this would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In what event are you adding this image to the tooltip? If it is in an AJAX request make sure that the tooltip is updated as well. You can also check the net tab to see if the request for your image actually returns an image and not 404, which would be a very good reason for a missing image.

You can also try putting an image in the markup and setting only its url from the server, or even via JavaScript on the client (for example in the OnClientShow event, by storing the URL in a hidden field).

You can also take a look at the Load-on-demand the RadToolTipManager offers, for example form the telerik demo site, for example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/tooltipversustooltipmanager/defaultcs.aspx), as it would fit very nicely with the way you dynamically create an image.

Comment: Im adding the Image on the Page Load event. I have checked the image is being served by the imagehandler by manually navigating to the .ashx page. I have also used Firbug to inspect the RadToolTip and the image is there, when i haver over it it shows the image in firebug but the RadTooilTip is still set to disply:none.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already are doing so but make sure that you have following kind of code in your code behind ( I use C# )

```
private void LoadTree()
{
      RadToolTipManager1.ShowDelay = 100;
      RadToolTipManager1.HideDelay = 100;
      RadToolTipManager1.AutoCloseDelay = 8000;
      RadToolTipManager1.TargetControls.Add("<ID Of the Control where you wish to diplay the rad tool tip>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.  I noticed some funky behavior with the RadToolTips after some recent updates...so I went to a RadToolTipManager with an Ajax update.  Just put your handler code in the Ajax event.

http://trappedinhoth.blogspot.com/2014/05/fixing-teleriks-radtooltip-after-latest.html

I hope that helps.